# Descobrir qual função é chamada no click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um site no wordpress e utilizo Bootstrap 4.

No rodapé tenho um link para voltar ao topo da página.
Quando clico nele mostra a animação da página subindo.

Gerei com javascript outro link para ir até o meio da página.
Mas a animação não funciona, ele já aparece no meio.

Os links estão idênticos

```
<a href="#topo">Topo</a>
<a href="#meio">Meio</a>

<div id="topo">conteúdo</div>
<div id="meio">conteúdo</div>
```

Alguém sabe o porquê a animação só funciona no primeiro link e não no segundo?

Comment: Qual o código *JavaScript* do *link **meio***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se com o seu **gerei com javasript outro link**, vc estiver querendo dizer que está adicionando um outro botão com javascript para que vá ao meio da página, você precisa aplicar o listener a este botão, pois o listener do botão que você está usando para ir ao topo já foi executado.

Ou você pode **gerar** este botão antes de aplicar o listener da tua animação de fazer o scroll por exemplo.

Comment: O problema era esse, tinha que gerar o link antes. valeu!!!

Comment: Boa, que bom que deu tudo certo